# WSO2 identity server implementation for single sing on for multiple web services deployed on different tomcat server

Tags: web-services, tomcat, wso2, single-sign-on

I am trying to implement wso2 single sign login. I have more than 5 web service. deployed on two different tomcat servers.

I have also tried your below tutorial

http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server/

and what i am able to do is successfully redirection when my web service is hit. But it redirects me to the WSO2 login page ( as I have configure wso2 SAML service provider ). And after correct username password its showing me you are logged in as admin.

What I need is a way so instead of redirecting to the identity server for login , I can pass username and password in my request only(from web service) and wso2 identity manager receive it check it and give me back the response. From response I should be able to identify the user is correct or not and if he tries to use another web service he should be able to do it (sso impl).

I just need the way of implementation not whole code.

Comment: I am continues trying and now understand that what method I was using was to forward control to IDP for authentication. And actually what I want was, instead of webservice redirect to login page of IDP it should pass request with credential and IDP should authenticate it and returned if user is authenticated or not? And I have found that this is possible by STS ("secure token service"). There are multiple ways you can do it and even you have OPENSAML api which can help you to develop your own. But Still i have to figure out how to achieve the same with WSo2 identity server.

Comment: A very good STS tutorial with CXF web service is available right here : http://web-gmazza.rhcloud.com/blog/entry/cxf-sts-tutorial. On the same blog you will also find how to use opensaml api.

Comment: Hi, have you found solution. if yes then please share it

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Working+with+Security+Token+Service) is the official documentation on how you can configure WSO2 Identity Server to work with STS. You will be able to implement your scenario with this.

Comment: YES Sumedha, I am following that only.. but issue is, When I use single sing on (with SAML ) in wso2 its redirecting me to login page of IDP, If I am using STS its for authenticate only one web service. How to achieve Single sing on with STS that is the issue. OR how to configure Single Singn ON with SAML that don't redirect you on login pag.